# Возможно ли получить имя входящей переменной?

Tags: php

Например функция

```
myfunc($var){
    echo "[(настоящее имя var)] = " .$var; 
}
```

если на вход подам

```
$g = "test";
```

то вывод примерно такой:

```
[(g)] = test
```

Comment: А зачем Вам это потребовалось, если не секрет?

Comment: Разумеется, нет. Передавайте имя явно.

Comment: Это понадобилось для обработки ошибок, чтоб я видел какая переменная на входе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашел на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

```
function varName( $v ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $vLine = file( __FILE__ );
    $fLine = $vLine[ $trace[0]['line'] - 1 ];
    preg_match( "#\\$(\w+)#", $fLine, $match );
    print_r( $match );
}

$foo = "knight";
$bar = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$baz = 12345;

varName( $foo );
varName( $bar );
varName( $baz );

?>

// Returns
Array
(
    [0] => $foo
    [1] => foo
)
Array
(
    [0] => $bar
    [1] => bar
)
Array
(
    [0] => $baz
    [1] => baz
)
```

Comment: Плюсик за debug_backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_var_name($var)
{
    foreach($GLOBALS as $name => $value)
    {
        if($value === $var)
        {
            echo "[($name)] = " . $value; 
        }
    }
}

$g = 'test';

get_var_name($g);
```

Comment: Это будет работать только для вызовов из global scope, во всех остальных случаях ее не будет в `$GLOBALS. Более того, другие переменные могут вообще не существовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо видеть имена переменных для отладки ошибок, то единственный способ - это анализ исходного кода. К примеру, в [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) эта проблема решена достаточно просто: выводится N строк кода вокруг строки с ошибкой и каждого вызова из backtrace.

[CErrorHandler::renderSourceCode()](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php#464):

```
/**
 * Renders the source code around the error line.
 * @param string $file source file path
 * @param integer $errorLine the error line number
 * @param integer $maxLines maximum number of lines to display
 * @return string the rendering result
 */
protected function renderSourceCode($file,$errorLine,$maxLines)
{
    $errorLine--;   // adjust line number to 0-based from 1-based
    if($errorLine<0 || ($lines=@file($file))===false || ($lineCount=count($lines))<=$errorLine)
        return '';

    $halfLines=(int)($maxLines/2);
    $beginLine=$errorLine-$halfLines>0 ? $errorLine-$halfLines:0;
    $endLine=$errorLine+$halfLines<$lineCount?$errorLine+$halfLines:$lineCount-1;
    $lineNumberWidth=strlen($endLine+1);

    $output='';
    for($i=$beginLine;$i<=$endLine;++$i)
    {
        $isErrorLine = $i===$errorLine;
        $code=sprintf("<span class=\"ln".($isErrorLine?' error-ln':'')."\">%0{$lineNumberWidth}d</span> %s",$i+1,CHtml::encode(str_replace("\t",'    ',$lines[$i])));
        if(!$isErrorLine)
            $output.=$code;
        else
            $output.='<span class="error">'.$code.'</span>';
    }
    return '<div class="code"><pre>'.$output.'</pre></div>';
}
```

Comment: ну это уж слижком для меня.

Comment: @Tolbase, может вам просто скачать Yii и подключить его обработчик ошибок?

Answer (score 0):

Имя переменной из функции никак не получишь. Но можно формировать массив типа ключ - значение. Где ключ это имя твоей переменная, а значение это значение переменной :).
Ну а по значению массива, найти ключ не проблема:

```
array_keys() //возвращает все ключи массива в виде списка
array_values() //все значения
```

Comment: видимо вопрос закрыт ответом "Нельзя".

Answer (score 0):

Быть может, ТС просто хочет изменять аргумент в функции глобально( просто догадка, для чего такое могло потребоваться )? Тогда в таком случае вам надо будет передавать агрумент по ссылке, а не по значению:

```
function modify(&$var)
{
   $var++;
}

function myfunc($var)
{
 $a = 0;
modify($a);
echo $a;  // 1;   
}
```

Comment: нет, никто изменять аргумент глобально не хочет, просто имя вывести и все.

Answer (score 0):

```
$abc = 123;

function showVar($name){
    echo $name.'=<pre>';
    var_dump($GLOBALS[$name]);
    echo '</pre><br>';
}

showVar('abc');
```

Comment: так вот кто поднимает мертвые посты! ловите некропостера! а если серьезно, то смотрите иногда на даты публикации вопроса.