# Создание переменной с идентичным именем внутри метода

Tags: php, функции

Передавая переменную в метод, мне нужно **либо создать такую же** переменную, **либо как-то перенести её** внутрь метода.

```
function foo($array) {
    // Создать переменную $hello
    // Или скопировать/переместить
}

$hello = "Hello, world!";
foo($hello);
```

Потом я вспомнил о ссылках. Но при таком раскладе:

```
function foo(&$array) {
    // Тут мне только доступно $array, а не переменная $hello (см. выше)
}
```

**Как мне перенести или скопировать переменную?**
P.S. Нужно только так и не иначе :)

Comment: а что мешает передать переменную вторым параметром в описание функции?

Comment: @Эдуард, хм.. ограничение на использование параметров. Нужно сделать только с одним.

Comment: @Эдуард, передавайте одним массивом, в котором будет всё

Comment: @КириллМалышев, ну да, конечно, что это мой второй вариант, если я не найду решение как сделать с помощью одной переменной-не массива.

Comment: ну либо получить название переменной: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/122070/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: @РавшанАбдулаев, см. комментарии к ответу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать ассоциативный массив, передать его в виде аргумента в пользовательскую функцию, в теле которой обработать этот массив с помощью  extract(). Таким образом вы получите желаемую переменную в локаоьной области видимости:

```
$array = ['hello' => 'Hello, world!'];

foo($array); // Hello, world!


function foo($array) {
    extract($array);

    echo $hello;
}
```

Comment: Да, идея то хорошая, а вот ищу ришение такое, чтобы не использовать массив. Пример: `$array="Hello";`

Comment: @entithat а чем вас массив не устроил? Если значений больше одного, то без массива (или объекта) не обойтись.

Comment: Я вот думаю на счет [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687363/php-access-global-variable-in-function) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Comment: @entithat на счёт глобальных переменных даже не думайте. Или передавайте массив, или несколько аргументов в функцию - это всё.

Comment: Очень жаль. Я надеялся, что *php* даст такую возможность.. Благодарю :)

Comment: @entithat вы меня не правильно поняли :) Да, в пхп конечно же такая возможность есть, но это идеальный способ выстрелить себе в ногу _(я про глобальные переменные)_